# Forçar via HTACESS uma única URL a rodar sem o httpS

Tags: htaccess

Tenho um site de ecommerce, ele está todo rodando com HTTPS, para isso coloquei esse código no HTACESS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Funciona bem, o problema é que eu preciso que uma única URL não sofra esse redirecionamento, ou seja, essa única URL precisa poder ser acessada sem o HTTPS, como fazer?

Comment: qual é a url que você quer deixar fora do HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso é uma solução possível para o seu problema.

Note que estou usando a url /test/httpOn e /test/httpOff como exemplo.
Substitua esses valores pela url que você quer deixar de fora do HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL off everything but /test/httpOff
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/httpOff
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# Turn SSL on for /test/httpsOn
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/httpsON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```